# How to draw a semi-oval shape using shape drawable in xml (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-drawable

[image: Android Layout of Oval Shape]

I am struck at this problem of creating the UI in android. I need a xml-based solution to this problem. I don't want to use any SVG or PNG image to achieve the solution. Is there any way to achieve this of view in android.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `<layer-list>` element of xml to draw such a UI.
Following code will be used to create oval shape:

```
<shape android:shape="oval"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#AAAAAA"></solid>
<size android:height="100dp"
    android:width="60dp">
</size>
```

This leads to the following shape:

[image]

Once you know how to draw an oval shape using xml. Now next step for you is to learn how to use `<layer-list>` to achieve desired output. To learn using `<layer-list>` you can follow [this](http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.com/2014/08/android-layer-list-drawable.html) tutorial.

Comment: I tried with many approaches. I couldn't make the figure. Could you enlighten me on this?

Comment: You do have basic shapes like oval, circle, rectangle by default in android drawable's `android:shape` property. But it is limited. you cannot draw every shape using it. So what you could do is, have a vector or png made in the shape you want and use custom drawable's `layer-list` component to place other items on top of it. I have provided a link in my answer that you can refer to, to do so.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a new drawable file which will describe the look of the widget you want to draw,more or less.You can then set it as background for which widget you want to change the original look of. I would recommend starting with rectangle if you want to achieve the shape shown in your question. the drawable file will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid
        android:color="#000"/>

    <corners android:radius="150dp"/> <!-- The value here should specify How much ovally you want shape be -->
</shape>
```

and then assigning the background of the widget to this drawable should do the trick, something like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/oval">
```

Hope this was helpful :D